# App crashes everytime after linking react-native-app-auth

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use react-native-app-auth for authentication purpose in my app. But as I link react-native-app-auth and perforn the necessary setup as mentioned in the official docs, the app crashes.[image: the app has stopped]

I tried react-native log-android to find the problem but I don't know what the issue is.
The output of react-native log-android

```
Starting the logger (/home/anita/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V)...
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
02-26 10:05:39.631 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:05:39.826 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:05:39.826 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:05:39.939 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
02-26 10:05:39.939 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:05:39.939 10347 10347 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:05:39.965 10347 10378 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:05:40.330 10347 10378 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:05:40.334 10347 10378 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:05:40.345 10347 10378 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:05:40.346 10347 10378 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:08:56.543 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:08:56.684 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:08:56.684 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:09:21.880 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:09:21.882 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:09:21.882 11122 11122 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:09:21.912 11122 12077 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:09:22.199 11122 12077 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:09:22.203 11122 12077 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:09:22.214 11122 12077 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:09:22.214 11122 12077 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:09:22.216 11122 12081 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:09:22.216 11122 12081 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:09:22.224 11122 12081 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:09:23.804 11122 12080 W ReactNativeJS: `createNavigationContainer()` has been deprecated, please use `createAppContainer()` instead. You can also import createAppContainer directly from @react-navigation/native
02-26 10:09:24.131 11122 12080 W ReactNativeJS: Importing the stack Transitioner directly from react-navigation is now deprecated. Instead, import { Transitioner } from "react-navigation-stack";
02-26 10:09:25.229 11122 12080 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "testApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 10:19:09.202 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:19:09.367 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:19:09.368 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:19:48.605 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:19:48.607 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:19:48.607 13534 13534 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:19:48.632 13534 13944 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:19:48.914 13534 13944 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:19:48.918 13534 13944 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:19:48.928 13534 13944 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:19:48.929 13534 13944 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:19:48.930 13534 13948 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:19:48.930 13534 13948 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:19:48.938 13534 13948 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:19:50.539 13534 13947 W ReactNativeJS: `createNavigationContainer()` has been deprecated, please use `createAppContainer()` instead. You can also import createAppContainer directly from @react-navigation/native
02-26 10:19:50.859 13534 13947 W ReactNativeJS: Importing the stack Transitioner directly from react-navigation is now deprecated. Instead, import { Transitioner } from "react-navigation-stack";
02-26 10:19:51.909 13534 13947 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "testApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
--------- beginning of system
02-26 10:22:04.839 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:22:04.965 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:22:04.965 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:22:09.486 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:22:09.488 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:22:09.488 15060 15060 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:22:09.515 15060 15310 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:22:09.813 15060 15310 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:22:09.816 15060 15310 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:22:09.829 15060 15310 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:22:09.830 15060 15310 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:22:09.831 15060 15314 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:22:09.831 15060 15314 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:22:09.841 15060 15314 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:22:11.444 15060 15313 W ReactNativeJS: `createNavigationContainer()` has been deprecated, please use `createAppContainer()` instead. You can also import createAppContainer directly from @react-navigation/native
02-26 10:22:11.770 15060 15313 W ReactNativeJS: Importing the stack Transitioner directly from react-navigation is now deprecated. Instead, import { Transitioner } from "react-navigation-stack";
02-26 10:22:12.819 15060 15313 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "testApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 10:31:24.616 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:31:24.711 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:31:24.711 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:31:30.553 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:31:30.555 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:31:30.555 16676 16676 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:31:30.588 16676 17016 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:31:30.923 16676 17016 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:31:30.927 16676 17016 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:31:30.938 16676 17016 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:31:30.939 16676 17016 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:31:30.940 16676 17040 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:31:30.941 16676 17040 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:31:30.952 16676 17040 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:31:32.620 16676 17039 W ReactNativeJS: `createNavigationContainer()` has been deprecated, please use `createAppContainer()` instead. You can also import createAppContainer directly from @react-navigation/native
02-26 10:31:32.942 16676 17039 W ReactNativeJS: Importing the stack Transitioner directly from react-navigation is now deprecated. Instead, import { Transitioner } from "react-navigation-stack";
02-26 10:31:34.007 16676 17039 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "testApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 10:35:00.551 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:35:00.643 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:35:00.643 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:35:03.035 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:35:03.037 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:35:03.037 18170 18170 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:35:03.066 18170 18420 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:35:03.415 18170 18420 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:35:03.419 18170 18420 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:35:03.437 18170 18420 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:35:03.438 18170 18420 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:35:03.440 18170 18459 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:35:03.440 18170 18459 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:35:03.464 18170 18459 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:35:05.131 18170 18458 W ReactNativeJS: `createNavigationContainer()` has been deprecated, please use `createAppContainer()` instead. You can also import createAppContainer directly from @react-navigation/native
02-26 10:35:05.458 18170 18458 W ReactNativeJS: Importing the stack Transitioner directly from react-navigation is now deprecated. Instead, import { Transitioner } from "react-navigation-stack";
02-26 10:35:06.576 18170 18458 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "testApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

The app works fine if I unlink it and undo all the setup. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me with this or suggest me any library to work with oauth2 in react native. 
Thank you

Comment: How about using expo? Of course, if you don't have packages that use native code. Check https://robertovg.com/blog/o-auth-2-with-react-native-keeping-expo/

Comment: I am using native code. Thanks

Comment: I see. Still, this article mentions ways to implement it without expo. Not sure if they are any good, though...